# Need to control AOS memory consumption

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

Here is my problem. I am working on a batch process that spawns multiple tasks. Each task is basically doing some journal postings. The tasks are run in parallel. Now the journal is a counting journal with close to 10k lines. This process runs for hours as there are around hundred journals to be posted. The process runs fine on physical dev boxes, AOS and SQL on same box. But on a virtual server, its behavior is different. AOS starts consuming all the memory while the lines are getting added and at one point, memory hits 100% and AOS throws out of memory exception and dies, other times process just hangs and waits for memory to be released, which takes a long time. The journal posting is standard AX process and is not customised. The AX environment is 2012 R1 and latest kernel hotfixes are applied (KB2962510). I explored this property called MaxMemLoad that allows you to restrict the memory an AOS can consume on a server, but did not help at all.

The AX environment is composed of three AOSs in a cluster.

How can i restrict this crazy memory consumption?

EDIT: 
Thanks to Matej i made some progress. SQL Server version was 2008 R2 SP1 and I applied the latest SP3. Interestingly out of three AOSs in cluster two now have much better memory graph, less than 45%. But the third one is still having weird memory usage. All three AOSs are same versions of AX, similar system configs (windows 2008 r2, 24 GB RAM, 4 cores). I had also applied the latest kernel hotfix on all AOSs. At the moment I am doing a full CIL on this particular server and run the batch again if that helps. I am attaching three graphs, generated using performance monitor, for CPU and memory, as you can see the memory on Server 01 is very erratic, not releasing memory on time, the other two are more stable. Any ideas?

[image: Server 01]

[image: Server 03]

[image: Server 04]

Comment: What it your SQL version (server/client). There is known memory leak in SQL Client (KB2422010, KB2881661).

Comment: Hello Matej, I need to check the SQL version, i am not having access at the moment. But the problem i have is AOS service consuming too much memory on its server. SQL server is on a different box. Are you saying SQL memory leak might cause AOS to consume high memory?

Comment: Yes. There is a known memory leak bug in some versions of the SQL **client**, which is used by AOS to access the database. Check SQL client library version.

Comment: Thanks Matej, i tried few changes. See my EDIT.